# What's the difference between $x/\mathscr E$={$y \in X$∣y$\mathscr E$x} and X/$\mathscr E$={x/$\mathscr E$∣$x\in X$}?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For example Let X={0, 1, 2, 3, 4} and $\mathscr E$ is an equivalence relation on X. $\mathscr E$ is defined as

$\mathscr E$ ={(0, 0), (0, 4), (1, 1), (1, 3), (2, 2), (4, 0), (3, 3), (3, 1), (4, 4)}.

Then for each x ∈ in X the equivalence class $x/\mathscr E$={$y\in X∣y\mathscr Ex$} determined by the element x are

Since x= 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

0/$\mathscr E$=[0]={y∈A|y$\mathscr E$0} = {0, 4}

1/$\mathscr E$={y∈A|y$\mathscr E$1} = {1, 3}

2/$\mathscr E$={y∈A|y$\mathscr E$2} = {2}

3/$\mathscr E$={y∈A|y$\mathscr E$3} = {3, 1}

4/$\mathscr E$={y∈A|y$\mathscr E$4} = {0, 4}

But what's X/$\mathscr E$={x/$\mathscr E$∣$x\in X$}? Can you give me an example of X/$\mathscr E$?

FYI

> "Definition 6. Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set X . For each x∈X, we define
>      ​$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$ $x/\mathscr E$={$y\in X∣y\mathscr Ex$}
>   which is called the equivalence class determined by the element x.
>     The set of all such equivalence classes on X is denoted by X/$\mathscr E$; that is, **X/$\mathscr E$={x/$\mathscr E$∣$x\in X$}**.
>   The symbol $X/\mathscr E$ is read "X modulo $\mathscr E$," or simply "X mod $\mathscr E$".

Comment: $x/\mathscr E$ is an equivalence class of $X$, whereas $X/\mathscr E$ is the set of all *all* equivalence classes of $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X/\mathscr E =\{x/\mathscr E\mid x\in X\}$ is simply the collection of the equivalence classes. So in the case of your example it is the set

$$
\{0/\mathscr E, 1/\mathscr E, 2/\mathscr E, 3/\mathscr E, 4/\mathscr E\} = \{\{0,4\}, \{1,3\}, \{2\}\} 
$$

(Only $3$ elements since $0/\mathscr E = 4/\mathscr E$ and $1/\mathscr E = 3/\mathscr E$)