# Can you give me an example of x($X/\mathscr T$)y?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Definition 7. Let $\mathscr T$ be a partition of a nonemptyset X. We define a relation $X/\mathscr T$ on X by x($X/\mathscr T$)y if and only if there exists a set $A \in \mathscr T$ such that $x, y \in A$.

I can differentiate [$x/\mathscr E$ and $X/\mathscr E$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1631855/whats-the-difference-between-x-mathscr-e-y-in-x%E2%88%A3y-mathscr-ex-and-x), but I don't know how exactly $X/\mathscr T$ is. The book doesn't give me an example of $X/\mathscr T$. Can you give me an example of x($X/\mathscr T$)y?

FYI

> "Definition 5 Let $X$ be a nonempty set. By a partician $P$ of $X$ we mean a set of nonempty subsets of $X$ such that:
>
> (a) If $A, B\in P$ and $A\neq B$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$
>
> (b) $\bigcup \limits_{C \in P}C = X$"
>
> "Definition 6. Let $\mathscr E$ be an equivalence relation on a nonempty set $X$. For each $x∈X$, we define
>      ​$$x/\mathscr E=\{\,y\in X\mid y\mathscr Ex\,\}$$
>   which is called the equivalence class determined by the element $x$.
>     The set of all such equivalence classes on $X$ is denoted by $X/\mathscr E$; that is, **$X/\mathscr E=\{\,x/\mathscr E\mid x\in X\,\}$**.
>   The symbol $X/\mathscr E$ is read "$X$ modulo $\mathscr E$," or simply "$X$ mod $\mathscr E$".

Source: Set Theory by You-Feng. Lin and Shwu-Yeng T. Lin

Answer (score 0):

Well, you know what it is, because the text just gave you the definition! So $X /\mathscr{T}$ is defined here as a relation on $X$; in fact an equivalence relation on $X$.

So suppose $X = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and the partition $\mathscr{T}$ is $\{\{1\}, \{2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}\}$. This is indeed a partition as we can check.

Then $1 (X/\mathscr{T}) 1$, $2 (X/\mathscr{T}) 3$, $3(X/\mathscr{T})2$, $4(X/\mathscr{T})5$, $4(X/\mathscr{T})6$ etc. etc. Two elements are related according to this relation iff they are in the same set in the partition. And every member of $X$ is exactly in one member of the partition (this is what the conditions for a partition come down to).

One checks by using the definitions that $X/\mathscr{T}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$, and its equivalence classes are exactly the members of the partition: in your notation we have $x / (X/\mathscr{T})$ (the class of $x$ for the equivalance relation $X/\mathscr{T}$ is exactly the unique member of $\mathscr{T}$ that contains $x$, and $X / (X/\mathscr{T})$ (the set of all equivalence classes) equals $\mathscr{T}$ again.

So the idea is: an equivalence relation on $X$ defines a partition on $X$ (the equivalence classes with respect to that equivalence relation), and conversely, if we start with a partition of $X$, we can define an equivalence relation on $X$, namely $X/\mathscr{T}$, such that its classes are exactly the members of the partition. So they are essentially the same way of looking at things, in that respect.